Periodic Signal RC Low Pass Filter Questions
I am solving a problem related to putting a periodic, non-sinusoidal C-T signal x(t) through an RC low pass filter. I am given the signal graphically, and am provided its period and amplitude.
I am given the capacitor value of C = .1uF, and need to determine what the resistor value should be such that the bandwidth of the filter is equal to the fundamental frequency of the given signal x(t).
x(t) increases linearly from 0 to 2 over the interval t = - .005 to t = .005, and then repeats in both + and - directions.
I was told it is necessary to use the fourier series coefficients c_k of x(t), found through integration, to determine the necessary fundamental frequency. I am confused as to why I am unable to simply use the formula w = 1/T along with T = .01s (given) to find the fundamental frequency as 100Hz or 200*pi rad/sec.
I then used the given capacitor value and this frequency, and solved for R = 15,915 ohms
I am additionally asked to find the Nyquist sampling rate, which I calculated as 200Hz or 400*pi rad/sec
The questions are shown below
TYPO in image 2
-"sample the filter output signal"" should say "sample the filter input signal"


Is this methodology correct or am I missing something involving the fourier coefficients?

I agree that figuring out the period via Fourier is not needed, it is the given repeat rate of the ramp signal, 100 Hz.
And based on wanting that as the RC cutoff frequency the resistance should be calculated correctly.
However, it's not possible to determine the Nyquist frequency from that alone, unless you make a very simple assumption that the RC filter is an ideal brick-wall filter. Only then you can assume that sampling a 100 Hz sine wave can be done with sampling rate above (but not equal to) 200 Hz.
The RC filter has a slope of -6dB per octave or -20dB per decade. So there will be significant amplitude of harmonics left at 300Hz, 500 Hz, etc, which will cause problems if sampling the signal at just above 200 Hz.
Without further knowledge, the answer to the asked question could be 200 Hz, in reality it depends on how much aliasing you need to avoid, e.g. 8-bit sampling is about 48 dB of dynamic range, so in order to the harmonics having attenuated by 48 dB in the simple RC filter, you need to sample 8 octaves higher than 100 Hz where attenuation has reached 48 dB, or almost two and a half decades.

Thank you. I added images of the questions for clarification of what its asking. Should I then be using the fourier coefficients to determine the Nyquist frequency? The question wants me to sample the input signal at the nyquist frequency, then plot it along with its FFT magnitude spectrum.

@user477684 The original, mathematical ramp signal has frequencies that go infinitely high. Filtering it means that the infinitely high frequency components are still there but just at non-zero amplitude. Without further info, you cannot have a Nyquist frequency defined. I don't know what you have been taught in a class where you need to solve this but it may require some assumptions about how this kind of assignment should be solved in this case.
